# Date.now() not a number in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

This Meteor server code stores a property `createdAt: Date.now()` expecting a number which is the epoch time, but when I view the document in mongo shell, I get `"ISODate(\"2016-12-25T22:31:09.553Z\")"`

```js
UsageCol.before.insert(function (userId, doc) {
  doc.userId = userId;
  doc.createdAt = Date.now();
  doc.period = new Date(doc.createdAt).getMonth() + 1 + '' + new Date(doc.createdAt).getFullYear();
});
```

Then, I wanted to change the date, so on the mongo shell I did:

```
db.users.update({'emails.0.address':'abc@zyx.com'},{$set:{createdAt:'ISODate("2017-02-25T22:31:09.553Z")'}})
```

But now I get:

> Exception while invoking method 'myMethod' TypeError: accMills.getMonth is not a function

```
let accMills = Meteor.user().createdAt;
let freeTime = accMills.setMonth(accMills.getMonth());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set `createdAt` as `Date.now()` it is not going to be set as a Date object but as a number that is the unix timestamp in milliseconds. So `accMills.getMonth()` is like `1490048577615.getMonth()`: it doesn't make sense. Instead you should do `new Date(accMills).getMonth()`

If you want to save a date object, you should set `createdAt` as `new Date()`:

```
UsageCol.before.insert(function (userId, doc) {
  doc.userId = userId;
  doc.createdAt = new Date();
  doc.period = doc.createdAt.getMonth() + 1 + '' + doc.createdAt.getFullYear();
});
```

Comment: If `Date.now()` is used in the before.insert hook. why then mongo is reporting `ISODate(\"2016-12-25T22:31:09.553Z\")` and not a number like 1488330383515

Comment: Yeah I was wondering. Can you share code on how you're creating the record at the first place?

Comment: It is the users collection. and I did not create the property createdAt, it is built in I guess.

Comment: Ok. It was not clear from your question that you were using the `users` collection. Not sure it's the best reference: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L1296 but it looks like meteor is using `new Date()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this `doc.createdAt = new Date().getTime()` it will return the date into epoch time format

UPDATE:
as @RobG comment Date.now() and new Date().getTime() is same.

Try this instead on set `$set:{createdAt:new Date('ISODate("2017-02-25T22:31:09.553Z")')}`

And n your freetime variable `let freeTime = new Date(accMills).getMonth();`

Comment: `new Date().getTime()` is equivalent to `Date.now()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to insert,update a new doc, use `dateCreated : Date.now()` from a js shell like intelliShell in STUDIO 3T for mongoDB which will give you a number as output.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29879829)