# I cannot solve a Basic problem of mongoDB Updating query using Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mern

Here's the document of mongodb:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("646fa9b33e467de3f38b2418"),
  price: 3500,
  orderConfirmation: false,
  dateConfirmationOrder: null,
  dateDelivered: null,
  clothID: '6450c20d7fd78c92313cd348',
  clientName: 'irtaza',
  clientNumber: 3320523524,
  desc: '11',
  address: 'Ahsan road, kala gujran, jhelum',
  marketerPayment: 200,
  marketerPaymentStatus: false,
  quantity: 1,
  deliveryStatus: false,
  marketerid: '644fae86bd576878837479be',
  length: '39',
  chest: '21.5',
  waist: '22',
  daman: '22.5',
  sleeves: '23.5',
  shoulders: '17.5',
  colloar: '14.5',
  armhole: '9.5',
  returnDate: null,
  returnDeliveredDate: null,
  returnStatus: false,
  returnDeliveredStatus: false,
  returnSentBackStatus: false,
  returnSentBackDate: null,
  returnDesc: '',
  dateOrdered: 2023-05-25T18:32:19.893Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

and here's the query:

```
orderModel.findOneAndUpdate(
          {
            _id: id,
            marketerid: marketerid,
          },
          {
            $set: {
              returnStatus: true,
              returnDate: Date.now,
            },
          },
          {
            writeConcern: {
              w: 1,
            },
          }
        );
```

I cannot find out the mistake why my record isn't getting update after this query!!!

Solving a Basic Update query problem!!!

Comment: it looks that you have missed `paranthesis` at `returnDate: Date.now`. Should be `Date.now()`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914938/date-now-not-a-number-in-mongodb

Comment: There is not enough information here to allow us to properly debug. In addition to the suggestion above, what is the response from the database when you run that command? What are the values of the variables (such as `id`) being used there? Have you made sure that the data types match (e.g. an `ObjectId` instead of a string)?

Answer (score 1):

Added parentheses to call the function ex.Date.now()

```json
orderModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        _id: id,
        marketerid: marketerid,
    },
    {
        $set: {
            returnStatus: true,
            returnDate: Date.now(),
        },
    },
    {
        writeConcern: {
            w: 1,
        },
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To find document by id, you need to use `new ObjectId()` instead of passing id as string.
`Date.now` returns a function, so do `Date.now()` to get current date timestamp.

```
import { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion, ObjectId } from "mongodb";

//... some code 

orderModel.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: new ObjectId(id),
  marketerid: marketerid,
},
{
  $set: {
    returnStatus: true,
    returnDate: Date.now(),
  },
},
{
  writeConcern: {
    w: 1,
  },
});
```